# How can I parse my xml in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, xml-parsing, flex3

I have the following XML structure:

```
<Order>
  <Mats>
    <mat>
      <item>
        <imgsrc>img_0</imgsrc>
        <cid>cid_0</cid>
      </item>
    </mat>
    <mat>
      <item>
        <imgsrc>img_1</imgsrc>
        <cid>cid_1</cid>
      </item>
    </mat>
  </Mats>
</Order>
```

In Flex, I am trying to get the first imgsrc and first cid. This is what I have so far:

```
public function globals_get_default_matte():void
{
    var defaults_matte_loader:XMLLoader = new XMLLoader();          
    defaults_matte_loader.url = Globals.defaultMatteXMLURL;
    defaults_matte_loader.loadXML();
   defaults_matte_loader.addEventListener("dataWritten",globals_get_default_matte_result_handler);
}

public function globals_get_default_matte_result_handler(e:Event):void
{
    var _xml:XML = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);
    if (_xml)
    {
        var mattes_list:XMLList = _xml.elements("Mats");
        var matte0:XML = mattes_list[0][0][0] as XML;
        trace(mattes_list);
        trace(matte0);
        trace(matte0.childNodes);
    }
}
```

In the Expressions tab, `matte0.childNodes` gives:

> errors during evaluation

Comment: Which node exactly do you want to access?

Comment: The goal is to get the 0th mat imgsrc and cid, so I want to get: img_0 and cid_0

Comment: Your are using XML like it's the former (as2/as3) XMLDocument class. Either use XMLDocument if it's really the wat you want to work or use XML the way it's meant to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not doing what you want:

```
var mattes_list:XMLList = _xml.elements("Mats");
var matte0:XML = mattes_list[0][0][0] as XML;
```

`mattes_list` lists the `<Mats>` node, then `matte0` does nothing more than select the first (and only) `<Mats>` node. Meanwhile, `childNodes` is not a property of `XML`, but the legacy [`XMLNode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/xml/XMLNode.html) object, which you aren't using.

You should familiarize yourself with [e4x in AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html). It's more like a query selector syntax.

To list the `<mat>` nodes and retrieve the first `<cid>` node, you can do this:

```
var mattes_list:XMLList = _xml.Mats.mat;
var matte0_cid:XML = mattes_list[0].item.cid[0];
```

Comment: (Expanded my answer a bit to explain *why* it's not doing what you want.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not too familiar with Flex, just trying to fix up some old code that is still in use.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. If you have a lot of legacy XML code, it may be easier to use `XMLDocument` instead of `XML`, which exists for the sole reason of supporting legacy syntax. However, if you can upgrade to e4x `XML` you'll probably find it much easier to work with.